# Read excel spreadsheet into a datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I am using the below C# code in my program to read excel 97 - 2003 spreadsheet data into a datatable using oledbconnection and ran into the name does not exist in the current context.

```
DataTable rs = null;

string path = Path.GetFullPath(filePath);
odConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';");
odConnection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(); ;
OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = odConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
string sheetName = string.Empty;
if (dt != null)
{
    sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Sheet_Name"].ToString();
}

cmd.Connection = odConnection;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
oda.Fill(ds, "excelData");
rs = ds.Tables["excelData"];
```

Comment: Add more details. Exception, line, which sheets does your excel has

Comment: Line 3, The name odConnection does not exist in the current context.

Comment: You have not declared odConnection so it does not exist. Try to add `var` before `odConnection` for example

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Thank you, is there a way to filter for one specific spreadsheet instead of looping on all. I have 12 different sheets and all I am interested is in just one spreadsheet.

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is example how to get all columns and rows from special Sheet from xlsx file. This code takes all data from `Sheet2` from xlsx file and fill the DataTable with that values.

Hopefully this will help you.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable rs = new DataTable();

            using (var odConnection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\Users\IIG\Desktop\test.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';"))
            {
                odConnection.Open();

                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = odConnection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet2$]";
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        oleda.Fill(rs);
                    }
                }
                odConnection.Close();
            }
            foreach(DataRow row in rs.Rows)
            {
                foreach(object item in row.ItemArray)
                {
                    Console.Write(item +"\t");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This helps

Answer (score 0):

Below line might be causing the issue -

```
if (dt != null)
    {
        sheetName = dt.Rows[0]["Sheet_Name"].ToString();
    }
```

Try using

```
dt.Rows[0]["Table_name"].ToString();
```

This should return the name of the sheet.